# Overcoming Rackspace Cloud Files 10,000 object limit

Tags: assets

Original question from Craft Slack:

Is there anyway to hack the `AssetIndexTool` to start at a certain asset/position/filename/index?

We’re using Rackspace Cloud Files and have around 25k images loaded. However, Cloud Files is limited to returning 10,000 objects per “page”. And it doesn’t look like Craft will paginate these objects. Wondering if we can just hack it to start the asset indexing at a certain place instead of starting at a certain index/filename, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Found the spot to hack this. It was not within the `AssetIndexTool` as originally theorized, but in the  In `RackspaceAssetSourceType` in the `_getFileList` function you can append a `marker` `marker_end` and/or `limit` to the file list.

The `marker` should just be a URI without the extension. As an example, we change the parameters on `$targetUri` to look like so:

`&format=json&marker=products/BC-174&limit=250';`

This will index the items form that marker and effectively ignore all the other assets you have already indexed. Craft will prompt you to delete the items you already have, as they are not found because you have skipped them by hacking the `$fileList`.

I've found you can safely hit *Cancel* and your items from the marker range will be imported, and your other indexes will not be affected.

[This article](https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/storage-api-reference/container-services-operations/#show-container-details-and-list-objects) is very helpful in finding out what you can do with the `marker` params.